# Is there any limitation in bit shifting?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Is there any limitation in bit shifting?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   int i=10;
   System.out.println(i<<32);
}
```

Output is 10

But I know its incorrect.

Answer should be 10*2<sup>32</sup> = 4.29*10<sup>10</sup>

Why is this?

Comment: A Java int is a 32bit, two-complement signed integer; I am surpised at all the the output of your prorgam is 10...

Comment: @Nipun but then your answer wouldn't fit in an int...

Comment: You can check another question similar to it [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817639/java-bit-operations-shift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817639/java-bit-operations-shift)

Comment: thanx I got the answer by using long i=10
yes int can't store that much size of value

Comment: If read the spec, shifting is always modulo the bit length of the shiftee.  (This is the way the hardware usually works anyway, so Java defined it that way to permit the simplest deterministic implementation.)

Comment: Most important thing is:

If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator &  with the mask value 0x1f. The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

so i<<32

here 32 = 0010000

five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand = 00000

i<<32 == i<<0

thankyou all to help me to understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `i` is an `int`,  only the 5 lowest bits are used.

The last 5 bits of 32 are **0**:

Your program is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(i<<0);
```

Which doesn't change the number.

If you want this to work, you should use `long` instead. See [this link](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-do-the-bitwise-shift-operators-work/12) for good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the shift-factor is modulo'ed by:

- 32, if the type of the shifted operand is `char`, `short` or `int`.
- 64, if the type of the shifted operand is `long`.