# java : shift distance for int restricted to 31 bits

Tags: java, bit-shift

Any idea why shift distance for int in java is restricted to 31 bits (5 lower bits of the right hand operand)?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19

```
x >>> n
```

I could see a similar question [java Bit operations >>> shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817639/java-bit-operations-shift) but nobody pointed the right answer

Comment: 31 is 31 bits, not 5 bits. It's restricted to that because an int has 32 bits, and shifting by more than that will always produce the same result.

Comment: Formatting code as such helps readability of the post.

Comment: I reformatted the question based on the sugestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shift distance is restricted to 31 bits because a Java int has 32 bits. Shifting an `int` number by more than 32 bits would produce the same value (either 0 or `0xFFFFFFFF`, depending on the initial value and the shift operation you use).

Comment: +1 - Still the question is "why did they choose to take the modulo 32 approach" instead of just returning `0` or `0xffffffff` - I suppose that both approaches would be feasible, so the answer is probably that it  simply was a **design decision**. [In C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270492/what-does-the-c-standard-say-about-bitshifting-more-bits-than-the-width-of-type), the same is undefined behaviour ...

Comment: Thnx yole and Andreas

Answer (score 2):

It's a design decision, but it seems a bit unfortunate at least for some use cases. First some terminology: let's call the approach of defining as **zero** all shifts amounts larger than the number of bits in the shifted word the *saturating* approach, and the Java approach of using only the bottom 5 (or 6 for `long`) bits to define the shift amount as the *mod* approach.

You can look at the problem by listing the *useful* shift values. Those are shift amounts that result in unique output values<sup>1</sup>. If you take >>>, the interesting values are 0 though 32 inclusive. 0 results in an unchanged value, and 32 results in 0. Shifting by *more* than 32 would again produce the same result as 32, sure - but java doesn't even let you shift by 32: it stops at 31! A shift by 32 will, perhaps unexpectedly, leave your value unchanged.

In many uses of `>>>` a shift by 32 is not possible, or the Java behavior works. In other cases, however, the natural result is 32, and you must special case zero.

As to why they would choose that design? Well, it probably helped that the common PC hardware at the time (x86, just like today) implements shifts in exactly that way (using only the last 5 bits for 32-bit shifts, and the last 6 for 64-bits). So the shifts can be directly mapped to hardware without any special cases, conditional moves or branches<sup>2</sup>.

Furthermore, for hardware that doesn't implement those semantics by default, it is easy to get the Java semantics by a simple mask: `shiftAmount & 0x1F`. That's going to be fast on all hardware. The reverse mapping - implementing *saturating* shifts on hardware that doesn't support it is more complex: you may need a costly compare and branch, some bit twiddling hacks or predicated moves to handle the `> 31` case.

Finally, the *mod* approach is quite natural for many algorithms. For example, if you are implementing a bitmap structure, addressable per-bit, a good implementation may be to have an array of integers, with each integer representing 32 bits. Internally to index into the Nth bit, you would break N down into two parts - the high 27 bits would find the word in the array the bit is in, and the low 5 bits would pick the bit out of the word. To pick the bit out of the `word` (e.g., to move it to the LSB), you might do:

```
int val = (word >>> (index & 0x1F)) & 1
```

That sets `val` to 1 if the bit was set, 0 otherwise. However, because of the way the Java `>>>` operator was specified, you don't need the `& 0x1F` part at all, because it is already implied in the *mod* definition! So you can omit it, and indeed the JDK's `BitSet` uses exactly that trick.

---

<sup>1</sup> Granted, any value without a 1 in the MSB may not produce unique values under `>>>`, once all the 1s get shifted off, so let's just talk about any value with a leading one.

<sup>2</sup> For what it's worth, I checked ARM and the [semantics are even weirder](https://david.wragg.org/blog/2012/11/shift-instructions.html): for variable shifts, the bottom *eight bits* of the shift amount is used. So the shift is a weird hybrid - it is effectively a saturating shift once you exceed 31, but *only* up to 255, at which point it loops around and suddenly has non-zero values for the next 31 values, etc.